# Lyx skipping numbers when indexing my tables

Tags: tables, lyx, captionof

I used code box with code "`\captionof{table}{*}`" followed by the table for my 3 tables in the unnumbered subsection. Yet after I export it to pdf, the three tables are index 1, 3 and 5. I made sure there was nothing in between the tables and they still turned out to be index 1,3,5 rather than 1,2,3.

Could you please provide some guidance to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. // Please EDIT your question and provide relevant code: a) starts with \documentclass, ends with \end{document}, b) compiles when we copy it, c) shows your problem, d) was pruned from all irrelevant code, packages etc. // Thanks

Comment: For more information on an example specifically with LyX, see here: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample